# Django admin template is broken in production

Tags: python, django, templates, heroku

I'm working with django, and trying to deploy my app to heroku.

All is working without any problems in local (even with DEBUG=False), but when deployed to heroku, the admin template doesn't display when DEBUG=False.

I followed theses instructions to configure my settings.py : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

And here is my Procfile :

```
web: gunicorn bourse_logements.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Feel free to ask if yu need some parts of my settings.py, I will paste them

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT :
Here is my settings.py :
https://gist.github.com/e-goz/62f812ab1fa8f8268f94

Comment: Could you paste your entire settings.py please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean for "template is broken"? Browser return 404? can't open admin page? or just failed to load assets?

Comment: @Leonardo.Z : Page is loading, I can login, but the display isn't correct. See : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/991s28ec9bog0f0/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%20de%202014-01-16%2018%3A51%3A16.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't .gitignore the templates folder?

Answer (score 0):

*** Add This line to your setting.py***

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

**you have to also copy all admin CSS and JavaScript to your static path(within static folder)
like static/admin/"you staticfiles"**

Comment: ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX  is deprecated since Django 1.4 and people should run `collectstatic` instead of copying files manually

Comment: can you please let me know django version?

Comment: If you using django>=1.5 you have to ./ manage.py collectstatic .

Comment: I'm using Django 1.5.
I ran collectstatic, so it works locally, but I'm unable to do the same with Heroku

Comment: Here Is heroku specific setting that working on many project you can try this one. change paths according to your configuration. please see next answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try This setting as per your configuration on setting.py.

```
from unipath import Path
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)
PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)
sys.path.insert(0, Path(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))
MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("collected_static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_DIR.child("static"),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    Path(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
)
```

**# Heroku specific settings**

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

**# You can also try in your url.py**

```
if settings.LOCAL_DEV:
    baseurlregex = r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$'
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (baseurlregex, 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root':  settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```